# System.Drawing error in .net core web api when generating QR code with AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, qr-code

I got the same error with the reference [.Net Core System.Drawing error with AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762988/net-core-system-drawing-error-with-aws-lambda) . My web api function is given below,

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetUuidWithQRGenerator(string deviceId, string customerId, string seedValue)
    {
        var data = CommonFunctions.GetUuid(deviceId, customerId, seedValue);
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(data,
        QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
        Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
        return Content(Convert.ToBase64String(BitmapToBytes(qrCodeImage)));
    }
```

How to generate QR code with out using System.Drawing in .net core web api with AWS Lambda

Comment: Use aws-sdk package : https://medium.com/@o.3odai/generate-qr-code-using-aws-api-gateway-lambda-function-s3-and-nodejs-part-i-f6d2e044d2a1

Comment: I am using .net core web api(c#). So the link https://medium.com/@o.3odai/generate-qr-code-using-aws-api-gateway-lambda-function-s3-and-nodejs-part-i-f6d2e044d2a1 suit for my requirement? it contains node js.